# python: monitor hanging script?

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, xvfb

I have a python script that starts Xvfb display and runs selenium tests. sometimes the script seems to hang for no apparent reason and I need to stop it and start it again. This happens when the tests have been running for several hours.

How can I monitor this script and detect when it becomes idle so that I can make it restart itself?

I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably best to try to fix the problem first. Maybe set an explicit timeout in the selenium driver.

If that does not help, maybe dont kill the process next time, but attach a debugger and look in what place the threads are stuck in.

Comment: its hard to debug, sometimes the web application itself is causing the problems and I don't always have access to it so its frustrating when test suites fail on the weekend and come back on monday to find they stopped on friday night. what i need is a way to monitor the script, and restart it when its been idle for some time.